# How to make Tesseract work like a pythonic module

Tags: python, tesseract

Why can't I import pytesseract when I place it in the same folder like my executed python script? At least that is how other python modules work for me.

I'd appreciate a solution without `pip` or `apt-get` installing or path-setting, since I am developing a software for a beginner level windows user. It would be best if it just works, after copying the main folder on his system and installing python3.

Code:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2


img = '/home/artur/Desktop/test_images/frame_0000.png'
string = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread(img))
print(string)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/OCR/Pytesseract_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    string = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread(img))
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/OCR/pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(*args)
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/OCR/pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/OCR/pytesseract.py", line 172, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install teserract on windows as soft/app, not as a module.  here is link to download tesseract. 
  https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

also, you need to indicate tesseract.exe file's installation path in your code `C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe`. it may be differencet installation path for you so check it. The following code works for me :

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import pytesseract

#following line of code indicates installation files path. it may be different for you  
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("text.png"))
print(text)
```